# Stop awk to compare a variable with the next records

Tags: bash, awk

My problem is the following: I have a file, formatted in a way:

```
1 apple
3 pear
7 lemon
```

What I wanted to do is to add empty lines on the lines, which are not equal the value in the first column so that it would be equal in the output:

```
1 apple

3 pear



7 lemon
```

I tried to do it with awk :
`awk '{for (i=1; i<=10; i++) { if (i==$1) {print $0} else {printf ("\n")}}}' file`
But, of course, it makes a comparison of each `i` with all the lines in the file, whereas I would like to stop it as soon as the action is done, but keep the loop with increasing `i` value. I red the 'awk manual' and I tried such commands like *next*, *break* and *exit* but I didn't manage.
Thank you for any tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In awk, (based on the expected output):

```
$ awk '{a[$1]=$0;max=$1} END{for(i=1;i<=max;i++) print (i in a?a[i]:"")}' foo
1 apple

3 pear



7 lemon
```

Explained:

- `a[$1]=$0` put record to hash `a`, index on `$1`
- `max=$1` remember last key
- in the `END` iterate from 1 to `max` and `print` from `a` if there is a match or just a newline otherwise

Answer (score 5):

Without using `Array`, Practically zero memory overhead

**Input**

```
[akshay@gold tmp]$ cat f
1 apple
3 pear
7 lemon
```

**Output**

```
[akshay@gold tmp]$ awk '{while(++c < $1)print ""}1' f
1 apple

3 pear



7 lemon
```

**With numbers**

```
[akshay@gold tmp]$ awk '{while(++c < $1)print c}1' f
1 apple
2
3 pear
4
5
6
7 lemon
```

Comment: Lol, this is exactly what I was going to code but got distracted. TGIF. ++

Comment: @JamesBrown : Happens sometimes, not to worry :)

Comment: I'm not sure I see how this works? What is the 1 at the end doing?

Comment: @Stats4224 : `}1` it does default operation,print current record/line/row `{print $0}`, it can be any nonzero value

Comment: @AkshayHegde Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another `awk` solution (without using array):

```
awk 'p{for(i=p+1; i<$1;i++){print ""}} {p=$1; print}' file
```

**Test:**

```
$ awk 'p{for(i=p+1; i<$1;i++){print ""}} {p=$1; print}' file
1 apple

3 pear



7 lemon
```

Comment: A bit more complicated than it has to be: `'{for (++i;i<$1;i++) print ""} 1'`. Also, I don;t think the OP is looking for a blank char to be printed on every "empty" line.